# setting delegate of a custom class

Tags: iphone

i am working in creating a custom class which is subclass of UIWebview. But its delegate functions are not being called. How should i set delegate for this class. I know this is a basic question but it will be really good if some one could answer it. Thanks in advance.

My Code:

.h file

```
@interface PollackWebView : UIWebView<UIWebViewDelegate> {



}

-(id)initWebview:(CGRect)frame;
@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation PollackWebView


-(id)initWebview:(CGRect)frame {

    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)SetMyDelegate {

    self.delegate = self;

}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest");
    if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {

        // do something with [request URL]
        return NO;
    }

    return TRUE;

}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");

}
```

Comment: You do not set a delegate object at all. The methods cannot be called.  My answer below already says what to do. By the way: You should not implement delegate methods in view classes. This contradicts the model view controller paradigm.

Comment: thats what i asked you, how to set the delegate object

Comment: okk its done now its working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what your trying to do, you don't need a subclass. In the code you posted you have only used delegate methods, so instead of creating a subclass:

- Just use a normal UIWebView.
- In the class that creates and makes visible the webview, set the UIWebView's delegate to `self` just after you Alloc/init the UIWebView.
- Then in the header of the class that creates/makes visible the webview add `<UIWebViewDelegate>` to the end of the `@interface` line, just before the `{`
- Then put the delegate methods in the class's implementation.

Comment: i know that n have done that many times but now i wanted to do it this way... n its working fine.. thanks for commenting

Comment: Setting `self.delegate=self` is a sign that something is really wrong. The whole idea of delegates is to delegate responsibility to *something else*. What you just did is breaking a core principle of Cocoa, and will only lead to troubles farther down the road.

Comment: +1 on this. In most cases if you're subclassing foundation classes or things like UIWebView, you should think about your design. "Uses" is much more common, and usually the better design in Cocoa apps.

Comment: My comment was a reply to the first comment by @pankaj. My bad for not correctly labeling it as such.

Comment: Oh no problem, just a little confusing.